# Cant Publish to Azure Using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core Web App w/ .NET 5 to a Linux App Service on Azure. I am just getting a generic error stating

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. ((3/23/2021 4:11:58 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (3/23/2021 4:11:58 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
> The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
> Publish failed to deploy

I check the log file that it tells me contains more information, but it says the same thing as the output window.

I am experiencing this issue on every site in my app service plan. I have tried pretty much everything I have found online like resetting the publish profile, deleting and then re-creating the app service, and re-installing Visual Studio. I just started having this issue when Azure had a large outage about a week ago. Before then I never had any issues but I am unsure if it's related.

I also noticed when I go to edit the profile that is imported from the Azure portal and then go to the Connection tab if I try to validate the connection with the imported credentials it also fails. It gives the same exact error message as when I try to publish.

It is looking like I have a credential/permission issue but I am unsure of how to solve it. Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it is just a simple ASP.NET core app with no external dependencies? What command do you use for publishing? Do you have permission to the target directory?

Comment: @GrigoryZhadko It is an ASP.NET Core Web App with Microsoft authentication. I am just using the Publish window inside of Visual Studio to try and publish. I do have permission to the directory as I can modify it through the cloud explorer and the publish will work sometimes. So far the only work around that I have found is deleting the .config, Properties, obj, and bin folders and then cleaning the solution and then rebuilding it. It allows me to publish once but the next time after that I get the error message again. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You should be able to download the publish profile from your azure portal -> App service resource and inspect the credentials for Ftp or MsDeploy.
Also you can deploy it to your local machine and upload to the App Service via FTP with the ftp credentials.
Also check your cloud explorer inside Visual Studio to be sure is working properly.

Comment: I tried this and double checked to make sure the credentials matched in Azure compared to the publish profile file downloaded and it still did not work. I get the same error when trying to publish via FTPS in Visual Studio. So far the only work around that I have found is deleting the .config, Properties, obj, and bin folders and then cleaning the solution and then rebuilding it. It allows me to publish once but the next time after that I get the error message again. Thank you for your input

Comment: use MobaXterm to publish via FTP or another FTP client https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/ hard to help out if you do not provide more info on your MsDeploy, obviously you have some wrong file or metadata setup in your project.